# Analyse the difference between the selection of several options

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, interpretation, biostatistics

I observed several test subjects (insects) for several days. All of them had the possibility to choose between 8 options (different ways to go). It was supposed, that all 8 options have the same popularity.

This are the results:
10 choosed option 1, 15 option 2, 16 option 3, 9 option 4, 9 option 5, 38 option 6, 13 option 7 and 8 option 8.

It seems, that option 6 is the most popular option but I want to analyse this the statistical way. Since I'm a total stat newbie, I used google to find out, how I can do this. Somewhere I read that I could use a chi-squared test what I did using R.

```
> observed <- c(10,15,16,9,9,38,13,8)
> expected <- c(0.125,0.125,0.125,0.125,0.125,0.125,0.125,0.125)
> chisq.test(x=observed,p=expected)

    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  observed
X-squared = 46.068, df = 7, p-value = 8.48e-08
```

**What do the values for "X-squared" and the "p-value" stand for, what is the conclusion of this test? Are there any other (better) tests I can run on this data?**

Answer (score 0):

You really need to read some basic text on (bio)statistics! But, for a fast answer: **X-squared** is the observed values of the chi-square statistic, it has 7 degrees of freedom (`df=7`).

You are testing the null hypothesis that all the 8 possibilities have the same probability `0.125`. The very small p-value you got is the probability that, if the null hypothesis is true, you would get a chi-squared statistic equal to or greater than its observed value `46.068`.

Such a small p-value is generally taken as indicating incompatibility between your observations and the null.